# I'm having problems showing leaflet map in a bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I'm trying to put a leaflet map on a bootstrap tab, 
but it's not working. Not showing at all or missing tiles and in the wrong position .

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

This is an example of the problem:
[missing tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8r4L.png)

This is my code: https://gist.github.com/h3kr/991ac0ee5a88d0cecba27e91c886675e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the CSS file for Leaflet.

Let me quote the [Leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/download):

> The latest stable Leaflet release is hosted on a CDN — to start using it straight away, place this in the head of your HTML code:
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
> <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much @IvanSanchez , it is now loading inside the container , but some tiles are sill missing when the map loads , only when i resize the page , i get the whole map visualised .

Comment: That's a different issue: lack of `map.invalidateSize()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863904/leaflet-mapbox-rendering-issue-grey-area/17866865

Comment: thanks , still looking for the correct implementation for map.invalidateSize(). [sorry , new in javascript and listeners ]